# Command running on terminal but not on crontab

Tags: cron

I'm trying to run the following command on crontab but for some reason it cuts of a portion of the command. when I check /var/logs/cron. However, it runs when I run it on the terminal.

Command in crontab:

```
*/30 * * * *    user     find /home/user/recordings -name '*.pcap,SDPerr' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.pcap,SDPerr}.pcap"' {} \;
```

from /var/logs/cron:

```
Jan 10 11:00:01 server CROND[116349]: (user) CMD (    find /home/user/recordings -name '*.pcap,SDPerr' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0)
```

What am I missing here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your command has a % (percent sign) in it, which has special meaning in crontab. Therefore better to put "\" before "%" to escape it.